# When was a table created?

Tags: postgresql, greenplum

Is there any way to find out when a table was created in PostgreSQL or Greenplum, other than finding the underlying table and looking at the OS creation timestamp?

Comment: Yes, dupe. I did search but didn't find anything. Plenty of posts on last update time.